# In Eclipse, can I remove the red error markers?

Tags: eclipse

I need to view source files from a project (C++) that I do not intend to run. Loaded in Eclipse, it has many errors due to missing libraries. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to ignore (or at least not underline in red) those compile errors?

I want to use eclipse to view the code for the syntax highlighting, parentheses matching, etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's possible to tell Eclipse not to underline the text / show it in the vertical or overview ruler by unchecking all checkboxes in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors`

As you only want to view the code, I'd recommend another editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or (my personal favourite) [vim/gvim](http://www.vim.org/). Eclipse is a little bit too 'heavy' for just viewing code.

Comment: Disabling Syntax Errors in Code Analysis didnt help me on Mac. But this answer worked!

Comment: Preferences is in the Window menu!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the CDT plugin, which you probably are as you're using Eclipse for a C/C++ project:

- `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Analysis`.
- Disable **Potential Programming Problems** and **Syntax and Semantic Errors**.

Comment: how to disable only for one specific project?

Answer (score -5):

You can also just remove the C++ files from the source folders included in the build path.

Comment: this does not answer the question at all.