# Eclipse. Copied code is hard to read. How to disable warnings and delete comments?

Tags: java, eclipse

That is it, I'm tired of that problem: I have some source of java code it could be a manual or web-site or whatever but the format of this source often is not suitable for reading, so I copy it to a temp file in Eclipse and press Ctrl+Shift+F(Auto formatting), it's good so far but what next? My code looks like Christmas tree there are a lot of warnings about mistakes (mostly because this code is out of it's context) but I don't care I just need to read it

1) How I can disable all warnings? I need just be able to read and understand the code not to run it.

2) Is there a way to delete all comments and I don't mean folding them?

Comment: Hah! Christmas tree. Nice :)

Comment: do you really need eclipse? cant you use notepad++ or emacs or VIM or sublimetext?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624756/how-can-i-disable-compiler-warnings-in-eclipse-on-a-file-specific-basis

Comment: @Exeptional I've seen it, but I couldn't do what they described.

Comment: Why not just paste it in notepad++ and select java from the language selection if you don't care about warnings etc?

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949431/in-eclipse-can-i-remove-the-red-error-markers
2) find and replace - ^\s*?//.*?$

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your lint markers in eclipse. This will avoid warnings

Comment: In eclipse menu there appear a tool set

Comment: there you can see a checked box, click on the down arrow besides it and, there you'll find lint options

Comment: Or right click on the project folder > Android tools > Clear Link Markers

Comment: I have Eclipse Juno and I can't find what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Explore through this path location:

You can configure the Java Compiler to ignore the Deprecated Warnings. I'd suggest to configure this setting for the specific project, not globally. To do so, right-click on your project and go to Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings.

Comment: You tried it for yourself? I tried it didn't work. I create a project. I set "ignore" for all errors in it - no result